# Indexing data with Lucene.net

Tags: c#, lucene

I'm using the following function to index ebook data with Lucene.  I'm looking to improve the structure and organization of this function.

```
public string BuildIndex(int pageNum, int pageSize)
{
    var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    var version = Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30;

    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(version);
    DirectoryInfo path = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\LuceneIndex");
    Lucene.Net.Store.Directory directory = new MMapDirectory(path);
    using (IndexWriter iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED))
    {
        //Initialize the StringBuilder with 4 MB to accommodate our data
        StringBuilder bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder(4*1024*1024);
        var files = ReaderDAL.FetchBooklistSearchData(pageNum, pageSize);
        foreach (var file in files) {
            bodyBuilder.Clear();
            DirectoryInfo filePath = new DirectoryInfo(file.IndexFilePath);

            if (filePath.Exists)
            {
                foreach (var pageFile in filePath.EnumerateFiles())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = pageFile.OpenText()) {
                        String line = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        bodyBuilder.AppendLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }
            //file.IndexFilePath
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.Add(new Field("id", file.BookId.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
            doc.Add(new Field("author", file.Author, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("annotation", file.Annotation, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("publisher", file.Publisher, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("title", file.Title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("body", bodyBuilder.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            iwriter.AddDocument(doc);
        }

        iwriter.Optimize();
        iwriter.Flush(true, true, true);
    }

    watch.Stop();

    return watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function is called `BuildIndex`, but it could be seen as doing the following:

- Measuring its execution time.
- Creating an `Analyzer`.
- Creating a `Lucene.Net.Store.Directory`.
- Using the `analyzer` and the `directory` to create an `IndexWriter`.
- Iterating files
- Loading document body from physical file if it exists at specified location.
- Creating a `new Document` for each file, adding 6 `Field`s.
- Returning execution time.

---

The first thing that strikes me is that there seems to have a performance concern that shadows the code's intent: is the goal of the method to *build an index*, or to *calculate how long it takes to build an index*? The first thing I'd do is return `void` and remove the first thing in that list - focused code does *one thing*, it has only a *single responsibility* in mind.

The next 3 points are closely related and could easily fit inside a method whose job is to return a `new IndexWriter`:

```
private IndexWriter CreateWriter(Analyzer analyzer, string path)
{
    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    var mMapDirectory = new MMapDirectory(directory);

    return new IndexWriter(mMapDirectory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED)
}
```

The reason this method is taking an `Analyzer` parameter is because it leaves you the liberty of calling it and passing in a `StandardAnalyzer` today, and a `CustomAnalyzer` tomorrow, without changing anything in the method, only the way the `analyzer` gets instantiated.

In your original code, the `version`, `analyzer` `path` and `directory` locals all only exist to create the `IndexWriter`. Extracting the instantiation of this writer into its own method further reduces noise and increases signal. Consider this:

```
public void BuildIndex(Analyzer analyzer, int pageNum, int pageSize)
{
    using(var writer = CreateWriter(analyzer, @"C:\LuceneIndex"))
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Now `BuildIndex` doesn't care anymore about what Lucene version the `analyzer` is configured with; not anymore does it care about the actual type of that `analyzer` either.

---

The body of the `using` block declares a `bodyBuilder` variable that I would have simply called `builder`. In fact, the `StreamReader`, is part of implementation details of another method, just like the creation of a new document:

```
using(var writer = CreateWriter(analyzer, @"C:\LuceneIndex"))
{
    var files = ReaderDAL.FetchBooklistSearchData(pageNum, pageSize);
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        //Initialize the StringBuilder with 4 MB to accommodate our data:
        var builder = new StringBuilder(4*1024*1024);

        var directory = new DirectoryInfo(file.IndexFilePath);
        if (directory.Exists)
        {
            ReadAllPageFilesInFolder(directory, builder);
        }

        writer.AddDocument(CreateDocument(file, builder.ToString()));
    }

    writer.Optimize();
    writer.Flush(true, true, true);
}
```

The advantage of a `StreamReader` is that it allows you to load a large file's content in small chunks.. but [using `ReadToEnd()` is essentially the same as calling `File.ReadAllText()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3545407/1188513), so if the files are easily digestible it would be more easily readable to go that way:

```
private void ReadAllPageFilesInFolder(DirectoryInfo directory, StringBuilder builder)
{
    foreach (var file in directory.EnumerateFiles())
    {
        // is this file really a PageFile?

        builder.AppendLine(File.ReadAllText(file.FullName));
    }        
}
```

Moving the document creation into its own method makes it easier to later change *how* a document gets created (new field(s), new settings, etc.):

```
private Document CreateDocument(WhateverThatTypeIs file, string body)
{
    var result = new Document();

    result.Add(new Field("id", file.BookId.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
    result.Add(new Field("author", file.Author, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    result.Add(new Field("annotation", file.Annotation, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    result.Add(new Field("publisher", file.Publisher, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    result.Add(new Field("title", file.Title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    result.Add(new Field("body", body, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

    return result;
}
```

---

That's all nice, but now you want `BuildIndex` to measure its execution time and return it as a `string`, right? Wrong.

Let's say the `BuildIndex` method is located inside an `IndexBuilder` class; I'd make the method `virtual`...

```
public class IndexBuilder
{
    public virtual void BuildIndex(Analyzer analyzer, int pageNum, int pageSize)
    {
        // the above code
    }
}
```

... and then I'd create a class whose role is to *decorate* the existing functionality with another functionality, that I can substitute for an `IndexBuilder` wherever I need one:

```
public IndexBuilderStopWatchDecorator : IndexBuilder
{
    private readonly IndexBuilder _builder;

    public IndexBuilderStopWatchDecorator(IndexBuilder builder)
    {
        _builder = builder;
    }

    public override void BuildIndex(Analyzer analyzer, int pageNum, int pageSize)
    {
        var watch = StopWatch.StartNew();
        _builder.BuildIndex(analyzer, pageNum, pageSize);
        watch.Stop();
        // log watch.ElapsedMilliseconds,
        // write watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds to debug output,
        // and/or do whatever the original code is doing with that value.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm glad you are using `using` for your iwriter.

I also like the one comment you have included.  It states why the next line of code does what it does, not what it is doing.

The return value should be a `long` rather than a `string`.  I think this portrays you are expecting a number rather than an alphanumeric string.

I would standardize your use of `var`.  You start off using it very well, then you stop and start using the type in the declaration.

For the stopwatch start, I would just use `var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();` static method.  This allows you to get rid of the line to actually start the stopwatch.

The Lucene version should be a `const` within the class.  This will allow the compiler to optimize it better.

I would rename `iwriter` to `indexWriter`.  This will eliminate the confusion of what `i` actually is.  (In [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation), which I am not saying to use, `i` usually indicates the variable is an `int`, and it might confuse people).

If you have control of a document, I would make the add fluent:

```
public Document Add(Field field)
{
    // Add field as required

    return this;
}
```

Doing this will allow you to string the adds together:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.Add(new Field("id", file.BookId.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO))
   .Add(new Field("author", file.Author, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED))
   .Add(new Field("annotation", file.Annotation, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED))
   .Add(new Field("publisher", file.Publisher, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED))
   .Add(new Field("title", file.Title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED))
   .Add(new Field("body", bodyBuilder.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

Your return could be simply `watch.Elapsed`, I don't think there is any reason to have to stop it first.

Comment: Thanks for posting.  I don't have control of the `Document` class, but the strung-together `Add` calls look nice.